# UIView borderColor alpha value wrong

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

If I set the same UIColor with alpha to a UIView and its border, the colors do not match. The strange thing is, that the border gets an alpha value (it's not completely black), but it's not matching the view's background.

**Example**

Code:

```
let color = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.3)
let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
view.backgroundColor = color
view.layer.borderWidth = 5
view.layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Can you show/describe your desired result?

Comment: Is it because the border is "inside" the view (not outside), so it's 0.3 + 0.3 for its opacity (ie: backgroundColor + above border color)?

Comment: If you want the border to match the background, why add a border in the first place?

Comment: @Larme the view will have different states with different background colors, e.g. activated = white background, same border. For the default state I wanted "no border". But I think Sweeper is right, the colors are overlayed. I didn't consider that...

Answer (score 1):

If you want independent "inner" and "outer" colors, there are various ways to go about it.

Probably the most straight-forward approach is to create a custom `UIView` subclass and add an "inner" `UIView` as a subview.

The base view will have `backgroundColor = .clear` and the `layer.borderWidth` and `layer.borderColor`.

The "inner" view will be inset by `borderWidth`.

```
class BorderedView: UIView {
    
    override var backgroundColor: UIColor? {
        get { return innerView.backgroundColor }
        set {
            super.backgroundColor = .clear
            innerView.backgroundColor = newValue
        }
    }
    
    public var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get { return UIColor(cgColor: self.layer.borderColor ?? UIColor.clear.cgColor) }
        set {
            if let c = newValue {
                self.layer.borderColor = c.cgColor
            }
        }
    }

    public var borderWidth: CGFloat = 5.0 { didSet { updateLayout() } }
    
    private let innerView: UIView = UIView()
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        commonInit()
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        borderColor = .clear
        backgroundColor = .clear
        innerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        updateLayout()
    }
    
    // we need to change the "inner" views constraints when the border width changes
    private func updateLayout() {
        
        self.layer.borderWidth = self.borderWidth
        
        innerView.removeFromSuperview()
        
        // we need to keep innerView as the First subview
        //  otherwise it will be placed on top of any other added subviews
        insertSubview(innerView, at: 0)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            innerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: borderWidth),
            innerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: borderWidth),
            innerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -borderWidth),
            innerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -borderWidth),
        ])
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Since if we change backgroundColor, borderColor or borderWidth we should call updateLayout(), so it is enough to call `updateLayout()` inside `func layoutSubviews()`

Comment: @HassanTaleb - not sure why you edited my code? Your version ***requires an additional `.setNeedsLayout()` call*** to change the border width. It also **unnecessarily** rebuilds the view hierarchy ***every time*** the frame changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that when you set the same semi-transparent UIColor to both the background and border of a UIView, the resulting colors don't visually match. The border appears differently than the background, even though you're using the same color value for both. Although adding a border with same color of the background is useless.